# My 3rd monitor is stuck at 800×600 in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution

I am having some issue creating a 3rd monitor for my laptop.  I have an HP Pavilion 15-p080ca Notebook, with an attached AOC e1759fwu USB Monitor.  The graphics card is an AMD Radeon HD 8610G.

I am trying to hook up a tablet which supports 1920 × 1200 resolution.  The way to do this is to go into your Device Settings, detect monitor, and when the 3rd unconnected monitor turns up, you try and connect to it via VGA and it activates. My problem is this 3rd monitor is defaulted to 800×600 and the option to increase is grayed out.

[image: Display Settings > Screen Resolution]

This occurred no matter how I try to add a 3rd screen, either by using an Android app, or trying to set up the screen to be viewed by TeamViewer.

I have updated my graphics drivers, and no matter what I try, I cannot get better resolution. Does anyone know of a way to force it to have better resolution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AMD says:

*your graphics card must have EYEFINITY branding to allow three monitors*

and

*The first two monitors can connect to the graphics card with any display output on your product: HDMI, VGA, DVI or DisplayPort.
The third (or greater) display must be connected to the graphics card via DisplayPort.*

So you have to switch them around, and put the third one on DisplayPort, not VGA.

Comment: This makes sense, if I use my HDMI port for a 3rd screen it works fine. The problem is this third screen in this case is a "Fake" screen, which only allows you to "Try to connect on: VGA" only...

Comment: I have 2 HP monitors daisy-chained on DisplayPort 1.2 work perfectly. But the third one (ThinkVision) also connected on a separate display port (on a docking station) showing only these low resolutions on Win10 (Intel HD Graphics 620). But this Thinkvision if connected alone or 2 monitors setup comes with full resolution. Changing cables around didn't fix either.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen when the three monitors at full resolution exceed the capacity of the video system. Check if reducing the resolution of the first and second displays allows you to have a greater resolution on the third.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Custom Resolution Utility (CRU)](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU)

[YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpcte_5u1tg)

Google about EDID

Export EDID Configurations with [dumpedid.exe](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dump_edid.html) from NirSoft

```
dumpedid.exe -a > edid.txt
```

`-a` is active monitors.